# Array Transpose in Excel Interop 10.0 raises exception when character count < 32000

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

**PROBLEM:**

I am using ExcelWorksheetFunction[Transpose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.worksheetfunction.transpose.aspx)

```
object[] colValues = null;

colvalues = ... // Initialize and assign some string values to array and its length/count is greater than 0

mySheet.Range(startCellNumber, endCellNumber).Value = 
                      mySheet.Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(colValues);
```

Previously this was raising exception when string length(not array length) was `~ 159,000`.

We looked [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010073849.aspx) and it says that `"Total number of characters that a cell can contain"` is `32767`. We reduced length of string to 32000 and it works fine on Office 2010/2013 **but fails on Office 2007 even though its limit is also `32767`.**

**Exception:**

`Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC --Stack Trace--    at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData)      at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range.set_Value(Object RangeValueDataType, Object)`

What needs to be done that this works on Office 2007? I am using Excel Interop 10.0.

Comment: Any details on the exception?

Comment: @ChrisSpicer: Read my updated question

Comment: It is an unpleasant grab-bag of all kinds of problems.  Google "Excel error 1004" to find out more.